# Добавление нулевых указателей в контейнер

Tags: c++, указатели

```
stack<int*> st;
st.push(nullptr);
st.push(NULL);
st.push(0);
```

Что произойдёт при каждом добавлении?

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые вопросы. Для получения ответа поясните, в чем именно вы видите проблему, как её воспроизвести, что вы хотите получить в результате и т. д. Приведите пример кода в котором проявляется проблема.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 9):

Это может показаться невероятным, но при каждом добавлении в `stack`е будет становиться на один нулевой указатель больше. Более того, в конце выполнения их там будет целых 3.

Comment: @KromStern, не вижу в этом смысла. Контейнеры, которые исключают добавление одинаковых элементов не имеют никакого специфичного, для указателей, поведения. Я просто не понимаю смысла вопроса автора, не понимаю того, чего он не понимает, поэтому и расписывать что-то дальше не вижу смысла.

Comment: Согласен, логично =)

Comment: @KromStern, это противоречит одному из главных принципов ООП, который носит название полиморфизм. Контейнеры должны одинаково обрабатывать разные типы данных, а нулевой указатель не является каким-то отдельным типом - это все равно указатель.

Comment: @AlexKrass, на Java добавление `null` указателя имеет разную семантику в зависимости от типа контейнера (в некоторых случаях их добавление просто запрещено).

Comment: Почему тогда `st.Empty()` возвращает `true`?

Comment: @AlexKrass, может и нарушает, но встречается сплошь и рядом. Как пример, можно посмотреть на `std::vector<bool>`

Comment: Автор может пытается понять отличие NULL от 0 и nullptr, недавно сел за с++. Может не блокировать его минусами?

Comment: @viktor, у `std::stack` нет метода `Empty()` есть `empty() ` и он [возвращает](http://ideone.com/k1kExc) `false` в Вашем случае.

Comment: @nick_n_a, может и так. Но тогда и вопрос надо задавать «в чём разница между X и Y». Я не ставил минусов, если что.

Answer (score 4):

У вас стек указателей. В каждом случае будет происходить добавление `nullptr` указателя. `NULL` эквивалентно 0, в случае с указателями 0 эквивалентен `nullptr`.